# AWS Appstream upload application to default Images

Tags: aws-sdk

Can we upload and add our applications to already existing sample Images available on AWS Appstream2.0?

It gives the option of creating a new Image through Image Builder and then gives the steps ahead. But is it not possible that we upload our application to Images available by AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your application on the app stream using an interactive method or by uploading the application on s3.

The wizard that you use depends on your browser and application installer.

The 10 step process to deploy custom application on the App stream is [detailed here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream/latest/developerguide/appstream-add-app-interactive.html).